# Arduino expected ':' before '{' token

Tags: arduino-ide

I wanted to compile a project yesterday which always worked until now. Probably since an adjustment of the libraries (update) I have not been able to do this anymore. I ask for help.

ERRORMESSAGE:
exit status 1
expected ':' before '{' token

Line from Error

```
#define MSG_PRINT(...) { MSG_PRINTER.print(__VA_ARGS__); }
```

Comment: With all those compile errors in here, we should consider renaming from Arduino to Does-Not-Compile. - Have you even tried to google how to define function-like macros and how to use them?

Comment: what is the value of `MSG_PRINT(...)` after the #define directive  is evaluated?

Comment: What comes in your code just *before* you use `MSG_PRINT`?

Answer (score 2):

`MSG_PRINT` is a macro.  It gets replaced in your code verbatim *before* compilation.

The error message will give you more information. Specifically it will tell you *where* the error is. For example:

```
/tmp/untitled1/untitled1.ino: In function 'void loop()':
/tmp/untitled1/untitled1.ino:1:24: error: expected ':' before '{' token
/tmp/untitled1/untitled1.ino:12:13: note: in expansion of macro 'MSG_PRINT'
```

Here I have defined `MSG_PRINT` at line 1, which is where it "says" the error is. However that's only where the macro is. The actual error is at line 12, where the error says the macro is being expanded. That's the *last* line in the error message.

The little bit of code I used to trigger that error is actually a `switch` command where I deliberately omitted the `:` at the end of a case statement:

```
    switch (v) {
        case 3 // <---- missing colon here
            MSG_PRINT("foo");
            break;
    }
```

If we replace `MSG_PRINT` as the preprocessor would we end up with:

```
    switch (v) {
        case 3
            { Serial.println("foo"); }
            break;
    }
```

(I defined `MSG_PRINT` to just call `Serial.println`...) and now we can better see the context of the error.

With the expansion now in place it is obvious that there is indeed a `:` missing before a `{`, even though that `{` isn't immediately visible in your code.

Learning to interpret these sometimes cryptic error messages is key to working with C and C++.